# Recently update my MBP to Big Sur and I don't recognize the name in terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, big-sur

[image: terminal screen shot]

steltz is my username but I have no idea where "Omkars-MBP" came from? I've always owned this computer since it was brand new, so I'm not really sure what to do...but this is weird. Any advice?

Comment: the suggestion above fixed my issue after restarting my computer, however I'm still confused how it got set to "Omkars-MBP" which is totally random and honestly a little worrisome.

Comment: The highest rated answer at the question you were linked to seems rather obvious.  Whatever network you are connected to supports dynamic DNS and that name was registered previously to the IP you were receiving.